# The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

**I have an error on the "snap.snapshot.value" parameter in the following line "var map = Map <String, dynamic> .from (snap.snapshot.value);". The error is "The argument type 'Object?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map <dynamic, dynamic>'. "**

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  List<Posts> postsList = [];


  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();


    DatabaseReference postsRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("Posts");

    postsRef.once().then((snap) {

      var map = Map<String, dynamic>.from(snap.snapshot.value); <--- the error is here

      postsList.clear();

      map.forEach((key, value) {
        var values = Map<String,dynamic>.from(map);
        Posts posts = Posts
          (
            values['url'],
            values['descrizione'],
            values['data'],
            values['ora']
        );
        postsList.add(posts);
      });
```

Answer (score 10):

Would you change a code like below?

From

```
var map = Map<String, dynamic>.from(snap.snapshot.value);
```

To

```
Map<String, dynamic> map = snap.snapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>
```

Comment: the compiler does not give an error but when I do the build I get this error in the terminal: [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Comment: Please let me know error line. And you need to check this line 'var values = Map<String,dynamic>.from(map);' because you iterate 'map' and again get values from 'map'.

Comment: E/flutter (11796): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Comment: Try to change from 'var' to 'Map<String, dynamic>'

Comment: the error is on this line: "var map = snap.snapshot.value as Map<String,dynamic>;"

Comment: it doesn't work, it gives me the same error

Answer (score 3):

This is because **Map.from** function accepts a **Map<dynamic, dynamic>** but you are passing the `object` instead. So to pass as the same use casting like below :

```
var map = Map<String, dynamic>.from(snap.snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>);
```

Comment: Well done, the compiler does not give me errors but the application does not work because in the terminal I have this error: "The following assertion was thrown building:
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package: flutter / src / widgets / text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 378 pos 10: 'data! = Null' ", where does it come from?

Comment: This error is related to your Text widget. I guess you have pasted a variable inside Text and because that variable doesn't have any value so this error is being thrown.

Comment: how do i find the error line and fix it?

Comment: I think in the console it would be showing line no. as well?

Comment: `Text
                  (
                  data,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),`

Comment: Either make sure that the data should not be null or just do like it Text("$data",style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1, textAlign: TextAlign.center,)

Comment: the same thing happens with the url: Image.network(url,fit: BoxFit.cover), the error is: The following assertion was thrown building:
'package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart': Failed assertion: line 25 pos 14: 'url != null': is not true.

Comment: you need to check in your code that whether these values are actually null or you are not getting them after that you have to place logic accordingly. Basically Text, Image widget doesn't accepts null values

Comment: is your problem solved?

Answer (score 1):

In your Posts model, you need to remove any explicit object casting.
e.g. change from

```
`Posts.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
comments: List<String>.from((map['comments'] as List<String>)) 
}`
```

to

```
`Posts.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
comments: List<String>.from((map['comments'] as List)) 
}`
```

so it's cast as a List and no farther

Answer (score 0):

```
var map = Map<String, dynamic>.from(snap.snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>);
```

to

```
var map = Map<Object?, dynamic>.from(snap.snapshot.value as Map<Object?, dynamic>);
```

Because Firebase Date DatabaseRef Require / fetch Data in Object Form So Convert The Map data Into Object?

Comment: I did the same and its Working fine